# Update dimensional array in a loop (c++)

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

The first 2 if statements `(i==0 and i==1)` work fine but not the others. I don't want to store a value in a variable for each addition, but to use an array that it's going to change with each loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int G[3][3];
    int SL[3];
    int SC[3];
    int i,j;
    
    cout<<"fill the array: "<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            cin>>G[i][j];   
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            
            if(i==0){
                SL[i]=SL[i]+G[i][j];
            }
            
            if(i==1){
                SL[i]=SL[i]+G[i][j];
            }
            
            if(i==2){
                SL[i]=SL[i]+G[i][j];
            }
        
            if(j==0){
                SC[j]=SC[j]+G[i][j];
            }
            
            if(j==1){
                SC[j]=SC[j]+G[i][j];
            }
            
            if(j==2){
                SC[j]=SC[j]+G[i][j];
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        cout<<G[i][j];
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<SL[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
    cout<<"\n";
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<SC[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters these arrays if they are declared in a function (for example in main)

```
int SL[3];
int SC[3];
```

are not initialized. So statements like this

```
SL[i]=SL[i]+G[i][j];
```

invoke undefined behavior.

There is no great sense to use numerous if statements.

What you need is the following

```
const size_t M = 3, N = 3;
int G[M][N] = {};
int SL[M] = {};
int SC[N] = {};

std::cout << "fill the array: " << std::endl;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++  )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    {
        std::cin >> G[i][j];   
    }
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    {
        SL[i] += G[i][j];
        SC[j] += G[i][j];
    }
}

//...
```

Declare the variables `i` and `j` where they are used that is in for loops. Also it is a bad idea to use upper case letters for identifier names.

Here is a demonstration progran.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t M = 3, N = 3;

    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    int b[M] = {};
    int c[N] = {};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            b[i] += a[i][j];
            c[j] += a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &item : b )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &item : c )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
6 15 24 
12 15 18
```

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of vectorized math that's in linear algebra, which your problem resembles, you might consider the standard library's `valarray` class. The loops for vectorized operations are already present in its overloaded operators, and its constructor will zero-fill (or fill with a provided value).

While `valarray` doesn't have native multi-dimensional indexing, it does support "slices", allowing you to work with individual columns and rows of an array that is nominally 1-D.

```cpp
const size_t R = 3, C = 3;
valarray<int> G(R * C), SR(R), SC(C);

cout << "Fill the grid: " << endl;
for (auto e = begin(G); e != end(G); ++e) {
  cin >> *e;
}

for (size_t c = 0; c < C; c++) {
  // sum of rows requires adding a column at a time
  SR += valarray<int>(G[slice(c,     R, C)]);
}
for (size_t r = 0; r < R; r++) {
  // sum of columns requires adding a row at a time
  SC += valarray<int>(G[slice(r * C, C, 1)]);
}

cout << "SR: "; copy(begin(SR), end(SR), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); cout << endl;
cout << "SC: "; copy(begin(SC), end(SC), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); cout << endl;
```

For this example, it may not look simpler, but if you are translating algorithms from, say, NumPy or MATLAB, it may be a better match.

Note that you can also ask `valarray` to do the sums for you, if you prefer. It may be easier to think about as follows:

```cpp
for (size_t r = 0; r < R; r++) {
  SR[r] = valarray<int>(G[slice(r * C, C, 1)]).sum();
}
for (size_t c = 0; c < C; c++) {
  SC[c] = valarray<int>(G[slice(c,     R, C)]).sum();
}
```